# How to make ngettext() works using the php-gettext library?

Tags: php, translation, gettext

I am using the [php-gettext library](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext). Following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RuqVDdC1cI),
I have set up the _gettext() function

```
    require_once("locale/gettext.php");
require_once("locale/streams.php");


$locale_file = new FileReader("locale/$locale/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo");
$locale_fetch = new gettext_reader($locale_file);

function _gettext($text){
    global $locale_fetch;
    return $locale_fetch->translate($text);
}
```

I also want to use the ngettext() function to translate plural texts. Now it does not work.  How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok I found it

```
function _ngettext($t1, $t2, $count){
    global $locale_fetch;
    return $locale_fetch->ngettext($t1, $t2, $count);
}
```